# Angular update keeps trying to install -next version rather than the production version

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am attempting to do a version update on Angular (8.0.4 -> 8.3.3).  When I try to do so, the CLI tries to install 9.0.0-next.5

I've tried searching to see if I've managed to turn on some sort of 'use RC' flag or something but I can't find any info on it.

```
Name                                Version                  Command to update
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/cli                        8.0.4 -> 8.3.3           ng update @angular/cli
  @angular/core                       8.1.2 -> 8.2.5           ng update @angular/core
  rxjs                                6.5.2 -> 6.5.3           ng update rxjs
```

C:\ProjAngular\SupervisionServices>ng update @angular/cli

Your global Angular CLI version (8.2.0) is greater than your local
version (8.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

```
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Using package manager: 'yarn'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 48 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "devextreme-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires ">5.0.0", would install "9.0.0-next.5").
                  Package "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.0-next.5").
                  Package "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.0-next.5").
                  Package "ngx-cookie-service" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" (requires ">=4.2.0", would install "9.0.0-next.5").
                  Package "ngx-cookie-service" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires ">=4.2.0", would install "9.0.0-next.5").
                  Package "tsickle" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "~3.4.1", would install "3.5.3").
Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
```

I've never seen this happen before and I've been using Angular since V2.

Comment: You are correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add the `--from` and `--to` tags if you want a specific version. Fun fact: google runs on a near-realtime copy of the master. It's stable, no worries.